# Create an array of object in localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

This code is about storing data in localStorage. If localStorage is yet empty I want to create an array of such type:

```
(Key:)Events (Value:)[{Date: "", Event: "", Participants: "", Description: ""}]
```

If there's yet some data in localStorage then runs the code **else if...**

```
if (tdAttr) {


    var fastDate = tdAttr.getAttribute('data-cell');
    var fastEvent = fastAddEvent.value;

    var events = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('events')) || [];
    localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(events));



    var addFastEvent = function () {

        if (events.length == 0) {
            //JS doesn't see the "events" variable inside this scope
        } else if (events.length > 0) {

            for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {

                if (events[i].Date == fastDate) {

                    events[i].Event = fastEvent;
                    events[i].Participants = "";
                    events[i].Description = "";


                };


                break;

            };



        };


        localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(events));


    };


    addFastEvent();

};
```

So, **issue #1**: Why doesn't JS define the ***events*** variable inside the firts **if** condition (console.log: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`)?

Though after **else if...** it does.

**Issue #2:** 
How do I create my array

```
(Key:)Events (Value:)[{Date: "", Event: "", Participants: "", Description: ""}]
```

inside the first **if** condition?
I tried

```
if (events.length == 0) {
    var events = [];
    arr.push({
        Date: fastDate,
        Event: fastEvent,
        Participants: "",
        Description: ""
    });

}
```

But it still doesn't see the variable **events** (even inside the **if** condition) and shows me the error.

**UPD** I managed to solve the **issue #2**:

```
       if (events.length == 0) {

                            localStorage['events'] = events.push({

                              Date: fastDate, 
                              Event: fastEvent, 
                              Participants: "", 
                              Description: ""

                            });
                        }
```

Though, still can't understand why the variable is "invisible" inside the first **if** condition. Let's say, there's no stored items when the condition starts to check, but I understand my variable

```
     var events = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('events')) || [];
```

like this - *We get stored items, if there are no stored items, we create an array.*
It seems like JS understands it like - *We get stored items or **an existing yet** array*

Comment: Please, create a jsFiddle and we'll help you. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I managed to solve the issue. Just in case if someone needs:
**localStorage['events'] = events.push({...});**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage